# How to match either one of the condition using glob

Tags: python

I need to have a list of files inside a path that are filtered or matched either one of these condition. I am not sure if I'm doing it correctly since I am pretty new in python.

```
import glob
fileName = ('*.a.gz','*.b.gz','*.c.gz',) 
filtered_list = []
for /tmp/myFolder in fileName:
     filtered_list.extend(glob.glob(/tmp/myFolder))
return filtered_list
```

Comment: This is not a valid Python syntax. /tmp/myFolder/ cannot be a variable name. Also, what is glob?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to search for those file name patterns in /tmp/myFolder

```
import glob

fileName = ['*.a.gz','*.b.gz','*.c.gz']
filtered_list = []
for name in fileName:
     filtered_list.extend(glob.glob('/tmp/myFolder/' + name))

print(filtered_list)
```